# PLACEHOLDER Stackoverflow CLI

Tags: app, placeholder, stackoverflow

### NOTE

The app does not do anything at the moment. I will remove this note when I am ready to put it in alpha.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

(not here yet, soon to be put here.)

### About

(See https://github.com/TylerMS887/so for information, https://tylerms887.github.io/so for docs.)

#### License

[MIT](https://github.com/TylerMS887/so/blob/main/LICENSE) license

#### Download

Currently in alpha stage, to compile and install (if using Un*x):

```shell
which git # If nothing appears, use apt to install: sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/TylerMS887/so.git
cd so
python3 --version # Make sure it says e.g. "Python 3.9.12", if not, install the newest
                  # version with apt: sudo apt install python3
                  # Or, on macOS, install with Homebrew: brew install python
pip3 install PyInstaller # using PyInstaller to compile
pyinstaller --console --name "so" $(pwd)/StackOverflowCommandLine.py
sudo install ./dist/so /usr/bin/so
so --version
```

#### Platform

Supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux (including WSL). FreeBSD has not been tested, if you tried it and this app works, let me know!

### Contact

Contact me at [tylermageeshields@gmail.com](http://mailto:tylermageeshields@gmail.com). **Do not attempt to ask me for my Stack Exchange password (or any of my other passwords), as this will not be accepted for security reasons.**

### Code

This program is written in the free and open-source programming language [Python](https://python.org). I use the Python `requests` library to develop this program, which is also FOSS. This program is also FOSS (including the docs), the code can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/TylerMS887/so).

### Planned features

- Support for other sites in the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com).
- Ability to alias commands.

### Development progress

Development progress can be found at https://github.com/TylerMS887/so/commits/main.

Comment: I cannot install it. It outputs: `script '/so/StackOverflowCommandLine.py' not found`. :(

Comment: @PetLinux The script doesn't exist at this time, it's just a bare repo with stuff like docs. I'm trying to write all the code as soon as I can (hence the word "PLACEHOLDER" in the title).

Comment: Okay. I'm glad to see you continue. :)